# How to specify CPU architecture on Travis CI

Tags: x86, travis-ci, cpu-architecture

I'm looking for approach to make builds on Travis CI with certain CPU architectures e.g. x86, x64, arm64. Does anyone have experience to create build scripts which allow to handle with it?

Answer (score 4):

You can run on ARM64 by specifying `arch`:

```
arch:
  - amd64
  - ppc64le
  - s390x
  - arm64
```

Reference: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-cpu-architectures/